# when to remove the plural s

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Since I was first learned English, I know that any number greater than 1 comes with s for plural (except for some exceptions like Mice and Feet).
6 Cars, 2 Trees, 3 Dogs, 9 Years

So if someone ask me how old are you I will say 6 years old

but when I read a report in news website I find they say
a 6 year old boy (not years)

so when to remove the plural s?

Answer (score 1):

You remove the -s when it comes to a compound hyphenated set of adjectives modifying a noun:

> You are a 6-year-old boy. (*6-year-old* acts as an adjective modifying
>   the noun "*boy*")

Or you can also remove it when it's a compound hyphenated noun:

> A 6-year-old is singing (*6-year-old* is not modifying a noun, because
>   it's standing as a noun by itself, it's a noun)

Since it's a noun, it can take plural form:

> 6-year-old**s** are playing in the rain.

If it's not hyphenated, "6 year old" is incorrect.

Comment: how to make that decision to use "s" or not when speaking?!